# Adding and updating details to SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two methods in MyDBHandler class, one for adding details and one for updating details. The user fills in a form and their details are added to the database and outputed as a listView. I want the user to be able to fill in the same form again to update their details. My problem is that when I first install the app then there are no records to update so I have to use the addDetails method which keeps adding new rows into the database when what I want to do is update the details using the updateDetails method. I can't update the details if there is nothing to update when the app is first installed.

**addDetails Method**

```
//Add a new row to the database
public void addDetails(Details details) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, details.getFirstname());
    values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, details.getSurname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, details.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, details.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS1, details.getAddress1());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS2, details.getAddress2());

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**updateDetails method**

```
//Updates user details
public void updateDetails(Details details){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Take new values from the details object provided
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, details.getFirstname());
    values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, details.getSurname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, details.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, details.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS1, details.getAddress1());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS2, details.getAddress2());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Update the details object where id matches
    db.update(TABLE_DETAILS, values, COLUMN_ID + "='" + details._id + "'", null);


    db.close();

}
```

**FragmentTab1 class**

```
import com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.*;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;


public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    //setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);
    firstName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    editTextName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    textView5 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surName);
    editTextSurname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);
    textView4 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    editTextMobile = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
    textView2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Email);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    textView3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.address1);
    editTextAddress1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress1);
    textView6 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.address2);
    editTextAddress2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress2);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);



    Button addButtonClicked = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addButtonClicked);
    addButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}



TextView firstName;
EditText editTextName;

TextView textView5;
EditText editTextSurname;

TextView textView4;
EditText editTextMobile;

TextView textView2;
EditText editTextEmail;

TextView textView3;
EditText editTextAddress1;

TextView textView6;
EditText editTextAddress2;

MyDBHandler dbHandler;



//validate email provided by user
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}



//Add details to the database and shared preferences
public void addButtonClicked(View view) {



    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    if (!isValidEmail(email))
    {
        editTextEmail.setError("Invalid Email");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email format",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else if( editTextName.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    {
        editTextName.setError("First name is required!");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "First name is required",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( editTextSurname.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    {
        editTextSurname.setError("Surname is required!");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Surname is required",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( editTextMobile.getText().toString().length() == 0 || editTextMobile.getText().toString().length() < 10 )
    {
        editTextMobile.setError("Not a valid number!");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Not a valid number",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( editTextAddress1.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    {
        editTextAddress1.setError("Address Line 1 is required!");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Address Line 1 is required",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( editTextAddress2.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    {
        editTextAddress2.setError("Address Line 2 is required!");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Address Line 2 is required",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Details details = new Details();
        details.set_id(1);
        details.setFirstname(editTextName.getText().toString());
        details.setSurname(editTextSurname.getText().toString());
        details.setPhone(editTextMobile.getText().toString());
        details.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        details.setAddress1(editTextAddress1.getText().toString());
        details.setAddress2(editTextAddress2.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addDetails(details);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Details saved successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: i didn't understand this part "when what I want to do is update the details using the updateDetails method.".. give us please some code from your activity to understand more

Comment: I can either use addDetails or updateDetails when the button is clicked to save the users details but I can't set the button to use updateDetails if there is nothing to update if you're getting me?

Comment: Is your database data is updated?

Comment: What? Dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check if the table is empty, to do so, create inside your 'MyDBHandler' a method called something like 'Exists':

```
 public boolean Exists {

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

   String Query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_DETAILS " ;

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Log.i("CHECK", "true");
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

then inside your activity call Exists something like:

```
 MyDBHandler db;
 db = new MyDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
 db.getWritableDatabase();

            if ((db.Exists( ))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please add first your Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
            //update your Database
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Would it not be that 'if' the table exists then I update my results 'else' add a new row?

Comment: yes, when method 'Exists' return false then you can update your table, else  your table is empty so the user get only a message "Please add first your Details"

Comment: But the button that the user clicks for adding and updating is the same button....I have to set it first to addDetails...then I have to reset it to updateDetails and run the app again